# TypeScript Conditional Operators - Variadic Tuples, why doesn't it work

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes any number of string arguments except the last argument which is a function. The string parameters are also optional, ie we don't have to pass any string arguments.

I want to type this function to ensure that we pass the correct parameters and in the correct order. ex: we can't pass 2 functions, or a function then a string.

What I thought would work but didn't:

```ts
function fn<T extends string[]>(...args: [...T, () => unknown]) {}
```

This failed, TypeScript did not error on these calls.

```ts
fn('45', '67', () => {}, () => {});
fn(() => {}, '23');
```

What worked:

```ts
function fn<T extends string[]>(
  ...args: string[] extends T ? never : [...T, () => unknown]
)
```

TypeScript errored on these calls, which is what I want.

```ts
fn('45', '67', () => {}, () => {});
fn(() => {}, '23');
```

Examples of valid function calls:

```ts
fn('45', '67', () => {});
fn(() => {});
```

Question:

In the case of calling

```ts
fn('45', '67', () => {}, () => {});
```

Why would `string[] extends T` evaluate to true ,but in

```ts
fn('45', '67', () => {});
```

It evaluates to false?

Comment: how do you know it's evaluating to `true`? I think the reason that example raises an error is for the constraint `T extends string[]` which obviously `['45', '67', ()  => {}]` doesn't satisfy.

Comment: Much easier would be switching the order - first required "function" parameter, then optional strings `function foo(f: Function, ...args: string[]) {}`